# How can I override meterial ui class in next.Js without global.css file?

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, next.js

I want to override a meterial ui class in next Js. I can override the class if I put the class in global css file but If I put the class in my module.css file and import it then It doesn’t work.In react I can use the class in my components css file and it works. Is there any way by which I can override the css class without putting the class in global.css file?

Comment: Are you trying to change default styling, or what is your use case?

Comment: I'm trying to change the font size and color

Comment: Sounds like a rule specificity issue, you may need to make the rule more specific in your module.css file